# How to get product collection of products with no website Id in Magento?

Tags: magento

I know that I have some products in Magento catalog that are missing websiteID totally. I am trying to find these products like this:

```
  $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
  ->getCollection()
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
  ->addAttributeToFilter('website_ids', 'null');
```

This will however crash. What is the correct method of fetching product collection of products without website_id set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All product website ids are stored in `catalog_product_website`. If you open this table here you can see the products associated with websites.

And here is the filter,

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

echo '<pre>';
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addWebsiteFilter('0');   

//echo $collection->getSelect(); exit;
$collection->getFirstItem();
 // ->addAttributeToFilter('website_ids', 'null');

//echo $orders->getSelect();

//exit;

 print_r($collection);
```

In this `$collection->addWebsiteFilter('0');`  filtering the webssite ids (currently 0), so you can change the value as1,0,2 or `NULL`. That's it.

In your case try with NULL or empty like ''.

**Update:**

If you filter with `''` you will get error, because the table  `catalog_product_website` having foreign key with product entity id and website id, which means the the `website_id` can't be empty. So try with direct query. In magento you can get query from collection by this,

```
echo $collection->getSelect(); exit;
```

or use this,

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `product_website` ON product_website.product_id = e.entity_id AND product_website.website_id IN('')
```

If you have any doubts, please comment here.

Comment: Thanks for help, but using '' or 'null' returns "Invalid website code requested" and using NULL returns all products. Maybe I have to do this through direct queries on tables instead. :/

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
SELECT catalog_product_entity.entity_id
FROM catalog_product_entity
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_website
    ON catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_website.product_id
WHERE catalog_product_website.product_id IS NULL
```